# Execute SQL DDL statements (with constraints) using PySpark

Tags: sql-server, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for a straight-forward way of executing DDL statements with PySpark to create tables in an Azure SQL Database.
I have different SQL DDL files that look similar to this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <table_name>;

CREATE TABLE <table_name> (id INT PRIMARY KEY, ...);
```

No approach I tried so far let me simply execute the SQL statement on a database. The closest I've come is something like

```
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE table1 (id INT PRIMARY KEY);")
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table1;")
df.write.jdbc(url=url, table="table1", mode="Overwrite", properties=properties)
```

This failed because apparently Spark does not support constraints, thus the "PRIMARY KEY" is problematic.

There already is an alternative ODBC solution implemented but it needs additional authorization by Azure that is difficult to set up while the Databricks connection to the SQL DB is already established.

Does someone know an easy solution to directly execute SQL statements (with constraints) in Databricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark uses Hive as a database abstraction layer over the Hadoop files system underneath. Hive database is a totally different concept than what you are use to from other standard database vendor.

For more details about the Hive Query Language, see [Hive DDL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL). You'll find other useful resource about Hive there as well.